# describe-face character not under / unreachable by the cursor

Tags: themes, customize, faces

I like using a combination of `describe-face` and `customize-face` to adjust the appearance of my working environment.  Sometime this workflow fails when I want to change the face of a location I can not reach with the cursor; mode-line, header-line, magit-blame headers etc.  Most of the time, I can trail and error my way to a solution but sometimes I get stuck (I didn't know the header-line existed until yesterday for instance).

Is there a convenient way to describe the face of a location in a frame which is not reachable by the cursor?  By means of a mouse for instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not know about using the mouse, but I've often found it's easiest for me to run  `list-faces-display` and then just i-search for what the face is likely called or visually scan for text that looks the same.

Comment: **This is the answer, IMHO.** The display is WYSIWYG, and it gives you direct access to the Customize buffer for a given face and direct access to a complete description.

Comment: I agree and changed the status. The other solution is cool but not convenient.

Answer (score 10):

There are 4 regions where text may be displayed in Emacs, here is what
you can do to inspect each of them.

- **The mode-line**: See the value of `mode-line-format`.
- **The header-line**: See the value of `header-line-format`.
- **Buffer**: If the face is in a region of the buffer you can't reach, see the value of `(buffer-string)`.
- **Minibuffer**: If point is currently in the minibuffer, you can do `M-: (buffer-string)`, and that will describe the contents of the minibuffer.
  You may need to `(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers to t)` first.
- **Fringe or Margin**: None that I know of.

These methods will give you the entire contents of these regions, so
it may take some reading to actually find the face you're looking for,
but it will certainly be there. Most importantly, it will describe even regions you cannot reach.
For instance, let's say I want to know
which face is used in the `find-file` prompt.

1. Invoke find-file with `C-x C-f`.
2. Describe the minibuffer with `M-: (buffer-string)`

That will give something like the following output, and right there at
the end is the face I was looking for.

```
#("Find file: ~/" 0 11 (front-sticky t rear-nonsticky t field t read-only t point-entered minibuffer-avoid-prompt face minibuffer-prompt))
```

Comment: Interesting!  I did not know `(buffer-string)`.  But how do I invoke it while I'm in the minibuffer without yielding "Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer"?

Comment: @remvee Ah, set the variable enable-recursive-minibuffers to t

Comment: What about the fringe?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis oh, good point. That I don't know.

Comment: I think that also leaves the margins?

Comment: @Sigma which margin? The fringe?

Comment: @Malabarba I meant the display margins http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html For example, the area that `M-x linum-mode` uses to display the numbers

Comment: In addition to fringe and margins, there are tooltips. (And the menu-bar and tool-bar, but one doesn't usually think of those as places to display text.)

Comment: @Drew can one customize text properties in a tooltip or in the menubar?

Comment: You can put pretty much anything in a tooltip, including text with properties. Dunno what you mean by "customize in". If you are asking whether you can customize faces for text shown in tooltips, yes, but probably only for use with property `display`. And no for the menu-bar, AFAIK. You can in some contexts (some platforms) control what fonts etc. are used for the menu-bar (using, e.g., Xresources), but not faces. Anyway, I was responding not to the question about customizing faces but to the description of the "regions where text may be displayed in Emacs". Sorry for any confusion about that.

Comment: @Drew not at all, I'm the one who was lazy because I'm typing on a phone. what I meant to ask was whether tooltips are capable of displaying faces, like different colors or underlining. I've messed a lot with tooltips in the mode line, and I honestly never tried that so it made me curious (and I'm at the phone =). Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I'm no expert on tooltips. I've used them to show images, and I know you can use the `display` text property to display practically anything in a tooltip. But I kind of doubt that you can simply put propertized text (i.e., text with faces) there. But try it!

Answer (score 4):

Turns out you can indeed use the mouse (I think this may be exactly what you were looking for):

```
  ;; based on: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19585/13444
  (defun brds/describe-char-at-mouse-click (click-event)
    "`describe-char' at CLICK-EVENT's position.
CLICK-EVENT should be a mouse-click event."
    (interactive "e")
    (run-hooks 'mouse-leave-buffer-hook)
    (let ((pos (cadr (event-start click-event))))
      (describe-char pos)))

  ;; <d>escribe
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c d <down-mouse-1>")
                  #'brds/describe-char-at-mouse-click)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in the modeline. Does it work for you in any places mentioned in the question?

Comment: Works for me on `magit-blame` headers, as well as, at a minimum, minibuffer completion candidates, the minibuffer prompt, and company popups. That said, it's not working for me either when I call it on the mode- or header-line: those give me `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p header-line)` (or `[...] mode-line`, respectively). I think those might be particularly special cases (along with the fringe and margin).