# How to change coloring in counsel

Tags: counsel

I am using `counsel-buffer-or-recentf` in order to toggle in files under buffer and recentf. The selected line is not clear, which has blue background highlighting.

[image]

=> Is it possible to change the coloring of the highlight? or can I remove the highlights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [ivy-faces.el](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/b472d347f6a3d31afe2807c0c0bb76a8ab128efe/ivy-faces.el#L30) for most of the faces of interest. The face you are asking specifically is called `ivy-current-match`. You wanna call `describe-face` and choose `customize this face` for customization.

Comment: Can I also changge the other face that is white on the example; like the one that is not selected ?

Comment: @alper A good command to use is `list-faces-display`, as suggested by [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/310/30574). It should be fairly obvious since the buffer display is WYSIWYG.